# Serializing C++ object to JSON

Tags: c++, json, xsd, xerces-c

If I am given an XSD file containing the schema of an XML, I can generate a CPP class that contains the code required for serialization and desrialization of the XML. I can use tools like xerces, xml booster, etc.

I know there is no Reflection in CPP like in Java. This means the ser/deser has to be done using code. Is there a way I can generate a CPP class from XSD or any other schema specification to serialize and deserialize in JSON instead on XML?

Regards,
Yash

Comment: I would not use XSD. There are several good open source C++ JSON Parser/Generators out there. I'm using JSON Spirit, but there may be something more popular now.

Comment: They don't generate a class that serializes itself into JSON.

Comment: I am looking for something that lets me do: Student s = new Student("John"); cout << s.JSONize(); The JSONize function should be generated for me.

Comment: Actually, from your previous comment, you want something more. You want something to generate the `Student` class for you from a schema document. IMO, unfortunately, a JSON schema standard is not yet mature enough (may never be unless it gains some traction in the community) for someone to build such a tool (i.e., like xsd, the tool, not the document standard).